# First tuple value in tuples list based on second value

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I get the first value of a tuple in a tuples list where second value is the minor?

```
mylist = [(a, date_a), (b, date_b), ..., (z, date_z)]
```

If `date_d` is the minor of all dates how can I get `d` ?

Comment: show an example with inputs and desired outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min` builtin actually accepts an optional `key` callable as a parameter, just like `sorted`, where it is more known.

which means you can customize what does it mean to be "minimal" for your sequence:

`min_item = min(mylist, key item: item[1])[0]`